# Python - Line too long, how can I break this?

Tags: python, pep8

I have this line of code:

`self.order_total = self.lineitems.aggregate(Sum('lineitem_total'))['lineitem_total__sum'] or 0`

It is too long for pep8 validation.  I had a look at the docs (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) but i can't figure out how best to break it.

Can someone advise me please?

thanks

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. There are many ways it could be broken. The "best" is purely subjective, and we don't take such questions here - please see [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, please don't use irrelevant tags for your question.

Comment: For most editors/IDEs there are pep8 format plugins or have a look at [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/)

Comment: One way would be to create temp variables: `aggr = self.lineitems.aggregate(Sum('lineitem_total'))` ; `self.order_total = aggr['lineitem_total__sum'] or 0`

Comment: Hi @Karl Knechtel, thanks for getting back to me about this.  I've read the link you have given me (plus https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and would like to ask, should I edit this question or ask a new one?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to make the question suitable for this site.

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo, I appreciate it!  Temp variables is something I don't know a lot about (I'm new to python) but it looks like it'll solve my problem pretty quickly!

Comment: It is nothing special or specific to Python. Just a way to break down long lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you mean `Line Breaking`. It is too easy

```
self.order_total = self.lineitems.aggregate(
    Sum('lineitem_total'))['lineitem_total__sum'] or 0
```

Comment: You are not kidding.  I tried something similar, but from I had been reading I thought that the indentation needed to be equal to the '='.  I clearly have a lot to learn still!